# Distribution of Isotropic Gaussian Blobs generated by sklearn.datasets.make_blobs()?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distribution, normal-distribution, multivariate-testing

Could someone explain the meaning of **isotropic gaussian blobs** which are generated by `sklearn.datasets.make_blobs()`. I am not getting its meaning and only found this **Generate isotropic Gaussian blobs for clustering** on sklearn documentation. Also I have gone through this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991961/gaussian-distribution-is-isotropic).

So,heres my doubt

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
# data set generate
X, y = make_blobs(n_samples = 100000, n_features = 2, centers = 2, random_state = 2, cluster_std = 1.5)

# scatter plot of blobs
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c = y, s = 50, cmap = 'RdBu')
```

[image]

```py
# distribution of first feature
sns.histplot(x = X[:, 0], kde = True)
```

**As the the distribution followed by this feature is approximately Normal.**
[image]

```py
# distribuution of second feature
sns.histplot(x = X[ :, 1], kde = True, color = "green", alpha = 0.2 )
```

**The distribution of the second feature is Bimodal which is not normal.**
[image]

```py
# overall distribution of values
sns.histplot(x = X.flatten(), color = "red", kde = True, alpha = .5)
```

**Which is also not normal!**

[image]

```py
# Variance Covrariance Matrix of Features
np.cov(X[:, 0], X[:, 1])
```

Output

```py
array([[ 3.55546911,  4.70526192],
       [ 4.70526192, 19.00023664]])
```

**What does it actually mean by Gaussian here!**. It might be a silly question so appologies in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sharing the things in the nutshell.
[image]

**The code snippet for understanding the** `make_blobs()` **is here.** [make_blobs_notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/Gkchandora/20a786df3017a9e02b5fc48a449fc9ee)